# Large floats in vector maths

Tags: java, math, game-engine

I'm building a Game Engine for fun and I'm trying to build a Vector3 Class using floats.
During testing I found that using large floats for x, y or z value causes the Vector3 math functions to break as the numbers they need to use are too large.

```
public Vector3f CrossProduct( Vector3f vector1, Vector3f vector2 ) {
    float x_ = vector1.getY( ) * vector2.getZ( ) - vector1.getZ( ) * vector2.getY( );
    float y_ = vector1.getZ( ) * vector2.getX( ) - vector1.getX( ) * vector2.getZ( );
    float z_ = vector1.getX( ) * vector2.getY( ) - vector1.getY( ) * vector2.getX( );
    return new Vector3f( x_, y_, z_ );
}
```

In the above function I can only use x, y and z values with a maximum of square root of Float.Max.

Is there anyway to have it so the components of the Vector have can be Float.Max?
The only way I know how to deal with this right now is by limiting the components to root of Float.Max.

Edit: I took Chnoch's advice and looked to see if other game engines have dealt with the problem in a similar way. From what I can tell with Unity3D and idSoftware's Doom3 engine ( https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG/blob/master/neo/idlib/math/Vector.h line 630 ), they just allow that the maximum float that can be used to be root float.Max. Come to think of it I don't really need very large numbers for what I'm doing.
Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Is that Vector3f with `cross, length, normalize` methods? Then the above would be the same as `cross`. You could first take the lengths, normalize and afterwards scale. Note that with `-` you would need to limit to half the square root of Float Max if I understood correctly.

Comment: Look at your expressions `vector1.getY() * vector2.getZ()` ; what do you expect to happen if any of the two is near Float.MAX_VALUE? *Of course* it overflows to infinity. Thats *expected* behavior for the float data type. Use a higher precision; eg. perform the caculations with double, then cast the result back to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is anyhow possible I'd just use double instead of floats. With doubles you get a 64-bit representation, which leads to a significantly larger range of numbers that you can access. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) for a comparison of the floating-point types.

In different math libraries there is a Vector3d class accompanying the Vector3f that works internally with double values.

Comment: So could I say use my Vector3f publicly and have a private inner class Vector3d for doing Vector3f calculations?
Or would I lose some precision converting between floats and doubles?

Comment: Well if you convert to a float in the end you're still limited to Float.MAX for the final result. Is it no option to just use doubles publicly?

Comment: Well there isn't any real need for Vector3f where the components can be larger than say root Float.MAX. It seems more efficient to just restrict the component size than cast to double for the calculation then cast back.

Although that said I took your advice and went for a two function solution. The faster function just restricts the floats to a Float.MAX and the other function casts to double then casts back to float so there isn't any limit to the size of the Vector3f components.